# How can I execute git diff in a Jenkinsfile and write the output to an empty text file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

My Jenkinsfile pipeline looks like:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'compute-env-spotfleet' }
    ...

    stage('Testing') {
        sh '$(git diff HEAD^ requirements.txt) > requirements_change.txt' 
        sh 'cat requirements_change.txt' 

       script { 
           env.FILENAME = readFile 'requirements_change.txt'
           ....
```

Then at the end I pass the file `env.FILENAME` as an argument into a Jira server, which gets rendered and the code is long and complicated, but at the end it says
`FileNotFoundError: [Errono2] No such file or directory`.

I am trying to debug or print out the contents of `requirements_change.txt`. I have tried everything under the sun to print it, but just can't seem to do it.

Any ideas how I can log/print the output of `requirements_change.txt` during the Jenkins build?

When I run the above I see:

```
[2024-02-04T21:07:26.877Z] ++ git diff 'HEAD^' requirements.txt
[2024-02-04T21:07:26.877Z] + diff --git a/requirements.txt b/requirements.txt index d2a0874f5..051e7889b 100644 --- a/requirements.txt +++ b/requirements.txt @@ -20,21 +20,21 @@ bcrypt==3.2.2 '#' via '#' -r requirements.in '#' paramiko -beautifulsoup4==4.11.3 +beautifulsoup4==4.12.3 '#' via -r requirements.in billiard==3.6.4.0 '#' via celery blosc2==2.0.0 '#' via tables -bmll-dbutils==2024.1.31.1 +bmll-dbutils==2024.1.30.1 '#' via -r requirements.in '-bmll-meta[full]==2024.1.30.2' '+bmll-meta[full]==2024.2.2.2' '#' via '#' -r requirements.in '#' bmll-meta -boto3==1.34.32 +boto3==1.34.34 '#' via -r requirements.in -botocore==1.34.32 +botocore==1.34.34 '#' via '#' -r requirements.in '#' boto3 @@ -47,7 +47,7 @@ 'celery[msgpack,redis]==5.2.7' '#' via '#' -r requirements.in '#' celery -certifi==2023.11.17 +certifi==2024.2.2 '#' via '#' requests '#' snowflake-connector-python @@ -121,7 +121,7 @@ lz4==4.3.3 '#' via -r requirements.in mako==1.3.2 '#' via alembic -markupsafe==2.1.4 +markupsafe==2.1.5 '#' via '#' jinja2 '#' mako @@ -182,7 +182,15 @@ pybind11-global==2.11.1 pycparser==2.21 '#' via cffi pycryptodome==3.20.0 - '#' via -r requirements.in + '#' via bmll-dbutils +pyjwt==2.8.0 + '#' via snowflake-connector-python +pynacl==1.5.0 + '#' via paramiko +pyopenssl==23.3.0 + '#' via snowflake-connector-python +pypcap==1.3.0 + '#' via -r requirements.in pysftp==0.2.9 '#' via -r requirements.in python-dateutil==2.8.2 @@ -194,7 +202,7 @@ python-gnupg==0.5.2 '#' via -r requirements.in python-snappy==0.6.1 '#' via -r requirements.in -pytz==2023.4 +pytz==2024.1 '#' via '#' -r requirements.in '#' celery
[2024-02-04T21:07:26.877Z] diff: unrecognized option '--git'
[2024-02-04T21:07:26.877Z] diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
script returned exit code 2
```

Comment: `git diff requirements_change.txt` will only show output in case you have uncommitted changes in the file - and I'm guessing you don't have that.

Comment: Ahh I see - I did make a change to requirements.txt locally and pushed it, so would that not appear?

Comment: You have `requirements_change.txt` and `requirements_diff.txt`, are they the same file ?

Comment: @kahhengchong No, you need to give it a version to diff against, like `git diff HEAD^ requirements_change.txt` would diff against the previous version

Comment: Ahh so sorry... that's a mistake - they are supposed to be both requirements_change.txt. Let me try to run it again

Comment: I have amended the question to reflect what I ran in the build. 

But now I am getting 
`++ git diff 'HEAD^' requirements.txt`
`+ diff --git a/requirements.txt b/requiremnets.txt index .....`
`diff: unrecognised option '--git'`
`diff: Try 'diff -- help' for more information.`

Comment: Where does `diff --git` come from? Did you write that?

Comment: Nope, I think that's the output. 

I've added the full trace to the question, I think that may be helpful :)

Comment: I can see that it is working, because the bmll-meta version changes from 2024.1.30.2 to 2024.2.2.2

Comment: Aha, ok, yes, it's the output from `git diff` - but that is not supposed to be executed. It's just for information, so don't do `sh '$(git diff HEAD^ requirements.txt) ...`. Just do `sh 'git diff HEAD^ requirements.txt ...` - By putting the command in `$(...)` you make `sh` execute the output from the command.

Comment: @kahhengchong Great! You're welcome! I'm a bit confused though, since in [your follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938089/how-can-i-extract-contents-of-a-text-file-and-assign-it-to-a-variable-inside-jen), you repeated the same mistake - and then in [your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77940138/how-can-i-turn-the-output-of-a-git-diff-into-a-big-string-and-assign-it-to-a-var) you did it again.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate of the question posed by you here: [How can I extract contents of a text file and assign it to a variable inside Jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938089/how-can-i-extract-contents-of-a-text-file-and-assign-it-to-a-variable-inside-jen)

While the above does work for using file file redirection, an easier solution would be to use the `returnStdout` option for the `sh` step as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77938371/21960203