# How can I extract contents of a text file and assign it to a variable inside Jenkinsfile?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

My Jenkinsfile pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'compute-env-spotfleet' }
    ...

    stage('Testing') {
        sh '$(git diff HEAD^ requirements.txt) > requirements_change.txt' 
        sh 'cat requirements_change.txt' 

       script { 
           some_variable = 'requirements_change.txt'
```

When I run the above in a build, the line `'cat requirements_change.txt'` prints a list of git diffs as expected.

However, I would like to assign those git diffs (as a string) to a variable `some_variable`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is able to be accomplished without writing the contents to a file by using the `returnStdout` option for the `sh` step like so:

`some_variable = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git diff HEAD^ requirements.txt')`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it does not work... some_varibable outputs an empty string

Comment: Hmm that should work, how are you outputting `some_variable`? Doing the following works for me:
`sh(script: "echo $some_variable")`
or
`echo some_variable`