# How can I turn the output of a git diff into a big string and assign it to a variable in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

My Jenkinsfile pipeline currently looks like this:

```
    ...

    stage('Testing') {
        sh '$(git diff HEAD^ requirements.txt) > requirements_change.txt' 
        sh 'cat requirements_change.txt' 

       script { 
           some_variable = 'requirements_change.txt'
```

When I build the above pipeline in Jenkins, the line `sh 'cat requirements_change.txt'` produces all of the git diffs of the requirements.txt file as expected.

Is it possible to turn all of these git diffs into one long string?
As I want to assign all of the git diffs to a variable.

The issue with the code written above is that `some_variable` points to the path/file of `requirements_change.txt`, but what I need instead is the contents of the text file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract contents of a text file and assign it to a variable inside Jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938089/how-can-i-extract-contents-of-a-text-file-and-assign-it-to-a-variable-inside-jen) - and the mistake of putting `git diff ...` in `$(...)` was cleared up in [How can I execute git diff in a Jenkinsfile and write the output to an empty text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77937441/how-can-i-execute-git-diff-in-a-jenkinsfile-and-write-the-output-to-an-empty-tex) so why are you doing it again?